# react forEach computes but does not display

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops

I have created a method that is supposed to go through all the elements of an array and display a challenge name {challenge} for each position in the array.
The code in the method works, I can see after doing console log, but it does not display the name.
Can anyone pls help?

Method:

```js
function createMultipleProgressBars() {
    console.log("create Method called");
    const progress = [];
    size.forEach(challenge =>{
      progress.push(
        <div key={challenge}>
          <p>{challenge}</p>
        </div>
      );
    });
    console.log(progress);
    return <div>{progress}</div>
}
```

Here is the entire code from my dashboard class:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./Dashboard.css";
import "./Dashboard.css";
import leafpic from "./img/leaf.png";
import TakeChallenge from "./TakeChallenge";
import Co2 from './Co2';


import Header from "./Header";
import { database } from "../firebase";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import firebase from "firebase/app";

import { ProgressBarContainer } from "./Progressbar";

export default function Dashboard() {
  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  var email;
  var size = [];

  if (user != null) {
    email = user.email;
  }

  const [showProgressBar, setShowProgressBar] = useState(false);

  function allowProgressBar() {
    setShowProgressBar(true);
    createMultipleProgressBars();
  }

  function createMultipleProgressBars() {
    console.log("create Method called");
    const progress = [];
    size.forEach(challenge =>{
      progress.push(
        <div key={challenge}>
          <p>{challenge}</p>
        </div>
      );
    });
    console.log(progress);
    return <div>{progress}</div>
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      var challs = [];
      await database
        .collection("Users")
        .doc(email)
        .collection("ChosenChallenge")
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
          snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
            challs.push(doc.data().chall);
            console.log("this is from .then", challs);
          });
        });
        size = challs;
      console.log("global size is", size)
      console.log("size.lenght is ", size.length);
      if (size.length > 0){
        allowProgressBar();
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);



  useEffect(() => {
    database
      .collection("Users")
      .doc(email)
      .set({ name: user.displayName, co2: 0 })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("added!");
      });
  }, []);

  const renderProgressBar = () => {
    if (showProgressBar) {
      //return <ProgressBarContainer onChange={handleChange} />;
      return createMultipleProgressBars();
    } else {
      return (
        <p>
          Oh no! You have not committed to any challenges yet. Click on the +
          sign in the bottom to begin
        </p>
      );
    }
  };


  /*<ProgressBarContainer onChange={handleChange} />*/
  return (
    <div className="Dashboard">
      <Header />
      <div className="circle">
        <img id="leafpicture" src={leafpic} alt="eco-picture" />
        <div className="textIn">
          <h1> You saved </h1>
          <h5><Co2 user= {email} />kg CO2</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="progressbar">
        <h3>Track your challenges!</h3>
        <div>
          {renderProgressBar()}
        </div>
      </div>
      <br />
      <br />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it also does not display anything

Comment: can you please paste your whole code ?

Comment: I have posted the code

Answer (score 2):

You are not returning the jsx, you are filling the array with the elements. Also you should use the map function instead. Try it like this:

```
function createMultipleProgressBars() {
    console.log("create Method called");
   
    size.map(challenge =>{
     return <div key={challenge}>
          <p>{challenge}</p>
        </div>
         });
 
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it does not work :( nothing is still displayed

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the size items using [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Also you need to add the size variable to the component state, and update it's value:

```
export default function Dashboard() {
  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  var email;
  const [size, setSize = useState([]); // add size to the component state

  //...

  function createMultipleProgressBars() {
     return <div>{size.map(challenge => (<div key={challenge}>
          <p>{challenge}</p>
        </div>))}</div>
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      var challs = [];
      await database
        .collection("Users")
        .doc(email)
        .collection("ChosenChallenge")
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
          snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
            challs.push(doc.data().chall);
            console.log("this is from .then", challs);
          });
        });
        setSize(challs); // update size value;
      console.log("global size is", size)
      console.log("size.lenght is ", size.length);
      if (size.length > 0){
        allowProgressBar();
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it does not work :( nothing is still displayed

Comment: Yes, you need to add size to the component state, I will update my answer

Comment: Thank you!  I have updated my code but it still not display and the useState does not update. It has printed it for a second and then it disappeared

Comment: Also this part should be: if (challs.length > 0){
        allowProgressBar();
      }

Comment: Thank you! Now it works! Highly appreciated!